# How do we set up migration paths for off-topic questions?

Tags: support, migration

This [question about windows](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/q/826/38) is much better suited for diy.stackexchange.com.

I voted to close, but the only option for a migration path is currently Woodworking Meta. How do we establish another Stack Exchange website as a migration path? I can see DIY being the primary one we'll be migrating questions to, so it should definitely be included as one of the 5 possible options.

Comment: The mods most have gotten the memo because when I voted to close, diy.stackexchange.com was offered as a migration path.

Answer (score 1):

It would be interesting if one or two others could be set.  However, I flag them for moderator attention and put in a note saying where I think they should be migrated to.

Comment: Good guess that DIY would be one of the more common ones.